# Make if == statement with Scanner nextInt

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

I am trying to make a match game where random numbers will show on the console then you have to type back the same numbers. I am having a problem with the if statement where it shows incorrect even when I input the right numbers. Here is my code so far:

```java
package MatchGame;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class match2 {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;

    String countdown[] = {
        "3...",
        "2...",
        "1..."
    };

    public match2() throws InterruptedException {
        set1();
    }

    public void set1() throws InterruptedException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("press ENTER for your first set...");
        s.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < countdown.length; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(countdown[i]);
        }

        a = number();
        b = number();
        c = number();
        d = number();

        System.out.print(a);
        System.out.print(b);
        System.out.print(c);
        System.out.print(d);
        int set = a + b + c + d;
        int guess = s.nextInt();
        {
            if(set == guess) {
                System.out.println("Nice bruh +1");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Nope");
            }
        }   
    }

    public static int number(){
        Random r = new Random();
        int match = r.nextInt(9) + 1;
        //rv = rv + match;
        return match;
    }
}
```

Also the variable 'set' doesn't seem to include the variables a, b, c, and d in it.

Comment: when I play the script to the console it generates four random numbers then asks you to type them back. It will eventually be a matching game. right now I can see the random set of numbers right in front of me on the console but when I type them back it always gives the "nope" reply. The guess is what I input using Scanner.

Comment: Please [edit] to add info, instead of hiding it in a comment.

Comment: Are you entering the four numbers or their sum? I think if you enter their sum it might work, because that is what your program is comparing with. It seems you expect something else, but I do not understand what that is.

Comment: I found that the problem is the fact that the variable 'set' is adding the integers together. so I need to find a way to make a set of the four variables: 'a, b, c, d' that is compatible with 'int guess = s.nextIn()t'

Comment: yes I just found out that the script expects a sum of the numbers. I want to make it so that you have to enter the numbers as a set. like this 1234. Not 10.

Comment: a,b,c,d are integers. set is an integer. You are adding intgers with an integer operator `+`. Then you compare an integer to an integer. What do you expect to be the result? If you concatenate string representations of integers, that would get you 1234 instead of 10. And you could compare a string to a string... I still don't get how you expect anything different than the sum...

Comment: I can't seem to make a String variable that includes the variables a,b,c,d without it taking them literally and it coming back as "abcd". Can you give me an exa,ple of how I could include all four in one variable".

Comment: Show your code which ends up in  literal "abcd", it sounds like there is an easy to fix mistake in that one but is otherwise much closer to this.

Answer (score 0):

An easy method would be to store your values and input to two arrays two separate arrays and compare both instead.

Comment: If i did two arrayLists would I have to make two new classes? I dont know how to add to ArrayList something that is in the same class. I only know how to add an Object / constructor. could you give an example?